# hcmap with a local file javascript in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am developing an application on shiny (ui and server), and I want to implement a map with the hcmap function of the Highchart package. But, when implementing the map I found that there is a dependence of the function hcmap with the site: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/.

So my goal is to implement the map but with the associated javascript file in a local way without using an internet connection. I tried the following solution: I retrieved the javascript file from https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ and I listed it in the www directory, but it did not give me any good results . Here is the code I used:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(highcharter)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(

dashboardPagePlus(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
fluidRow(box(width = 6,title="map",highchartOutput("map")))
    )
        )
          )

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$map=renderHighchart({
data_fake=data.frame(code=c("RZ","MT","TD","OR","FB","SM","MK","DA"
,"GE","LB","OD","TO","TH","GB","CO","GC"),
value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
                 )

hcmap(map=tags$head(tags$script(src="map.js")), data = data_fake, value = 
"value",joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"), name = "Fake 
data",download_map_data=FALSE,
dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.name}'),
borderColor = "gray", borderWidth = 0.9,
tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2, valuePrefix = "DH", valueSuffix = " 
MAD"))%>% hc_mapNavigation(enabled = TRUE)
})

})
```

I expect the output to be a map but without any dependency on the https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/ site, ie to use the javascript file in a local way in the directory of my application.

Map result with the code I used:

[image: Map result with the code I used]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let try another roundabout

1. using `trace(hcmap, edit=T)` modify hcmap in order to ruturn your desired map as and object:

Like this:

```
 if (download_map_data) {
    mapdata <- download_map_data(map)
    return(mapdata)
  }
```

2. Click Save in the edit window and execute: `my_map <- hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all")` Change the us map for your desire map.
3. Save my_map as RDS: `saveRDS(my_map, "my_map.RDS")`
4. Edit again hcmap:  `trace(hcmap, edit=T)`, now you want to read your stored map instead of downloading it:

   `if (download_map_data) {
       mapdata <- readRDS("my_map.RDS")
     }`
5. Click Save in the edit window and execute your desired map:

   p<-hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all", data = unemployment,
            name = "Unemployment", value = "value", joinBy = c("hc-key", "code"),
            borderColor = "transparent") %>%
     hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = color_classes(c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 50))) %>% 
     hc_legend(layout = "vertical", align = "right",
               floating = TRUE, valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = "%")
   p

It everything is ok, I will do the trick offline!

Comment: Remember NOT to put download_map_data to false when using this idea with your Code!

Comment: JonnyCrunch, smart solution, you're right it works perfectly offline. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ramos!

If your Shiny is using a limited number of maps, why you don't simply store then as RDS first you can retrieve them later offline?

```
data(unemployment)

p<-hcmap("countries/us/us-all-all", data = unemployment,
         name = "Unemployment", value = "value", joinBy = c("hc-key", "code"),
         borderColor = "transparent") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(dataClasses = color_classes(c(seq(0, 10, by = 2), 50))) %>% 
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", align = "right",
            floating = TRUE, valueDecimals = 0, valueSuffix = "%") 

saveRDS(p, "foo.RDS")
```

Comment: JonnyCrunch! , I appreciated your idea, but unfortunately the problem is that I have dynamic data and suddenly when I save the card in a local file .RDS I will lose the opportunity to change the data and suddenly I falls on the same problem of beginning ie using the Internet to recover a new card in which I will fill it with new data. I tried to save the obselete card and use it afterwards, but it gave me the same result as the screenshot above.