# Visualize bubbles on a map, using hc_add_series_map() instead of hcmap()

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I am trying to visualize a bubble map, using highcharter.

[image]

I did it perfectly, using this code

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

hcmap("custom/africa") %>%
hc_add_series(data = fake_data, type = "mapbubble", maxSize = '10%', color = 
"Red", showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
```

**My data**

```
> dput(fake_data)
structure(list(country = c("DZ", "CD", "ZA", "TZ"), lat = c(28.033886, 
-4.038333, -30.559482, -6.369028), lon = c(1.659626, 21.758664, 
22.937506, 34.888822), name = c("Algeria", "Congo, Dem. Rep", 
"South Africa", "Tanzania"), z = c(20, 5, 10, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = 
structure(list(
cols = list(country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), lat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), lon = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), z = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

External geo data for Africa originally comes [from this source](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) and used with `hcmap()`.

But I transform it into RDS and use locally. Available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuemwk8spqeyqsq/africa_map_data.RDS?dl=0).

**My problem that I cannot use my code and external data due to corporate IT security restrictions. I cannot deploy this code with Shiny/RMarkdown on Connect, it is blocked.**

So my solution currently

Use the same data in RDS format

```
africa_map_data <- readRDS("africa_map_data.RDS")
```

And use the `hc_add_series_map()` with local data instead of `hcmap()`.

```
highchart() %>%
hc_add_series_map(
map = africa_map_data,
df = fake_data,
value = "z",
joinBy = c("hc-a2", "country"),
type = "mapbubble",
maxSize = '10%',
color = "Red"
)
```

But it does not work well, I get a mess.

[image]

How to create a bubble map with `hc_add_series_map()` (or any other way) without 'hcmap' and pulling external data.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! You can use the trick here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727132/hcmap-with-a-local-file-javascript-in-r-shiny/54729295#54729295 to run offline  `library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

hcmap("custom/africa") %>%
hc_add_series(data = fake_data, type = "mapbubble", maxSize = '10%', color = 
"Red", showInLegend = FALSE) %>% 
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) `

Comment: @JonnyCrunch, I did everything. My problem - I try to deploy it on Connect, it does not work so far. It is RMarkdown with run:shiny. Pure RMarkdown works, but with Shiny it dies. My logs look like this 02/23 14:47:27.939
trying URL 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/africa.js'
02/23 14:47:28.199
Quitting from lines 16-22 (Test.Rmd)
02/23 14:47:28.200
02/23 14:47:28.201
Warning: Error in download.file: cannot open URL 'https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/africa.js'
02/23 14:47:28.213
155: download.file
02/23 14:47:28.213
154: download_map_data

Comment: That is why I am trying to run it, not using hcmap("custom/africa"). I need run it locally as RDS from my project directory. It will solve all pain.

Comment: Cannot you download the map in another computer as in the link above, move it to your local server and run the modified version of the function `hcmap` reading from your local host instead of the web? Best

Comment: @JonnyCrunch, frankly speaking, I am not sure what do you mean here. Can you elaborate please? That is what I am trying to clarify, how to run it from local directory, this Africa data.